# How can I add LIRE dependency to Maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I need to import lire dependecy on Maven but I can't found it on the Maven Central Repository.
How can I add it to my pom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [import jar manually to mvn repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id>
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

, and then reference it within your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group-id</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
  <version>version</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```